# Cleaning up file resources in a DRY manner

Tags: scala, io, exception

I've written a function that generates a report, and then sends it as an attachment to an email.  I don't want to clutter the function with a lot of calls to close up the filesystem, if there was an error along the way.  What do you all think?

```
// attempt to generate the report, any error will be wrapped in Failure(ex)
val op1 = Try {
  DB.withConnection{ implicit c =>
    generateReport(command.programId, token.claims)(output, c)
  }
}

// use (abuse?) pattern matching to send the report if it generated succesfully
val op2 = op1 match {
  case Success(_) => Try(sendReport(Address(user.email, user.first), file, command.created))

  // if the op1 value is of type Failure(ex), carry it forward until after the temp files have been removed
  case Failure(ex) => Failure(ex)
}

// the operations have either succeeded or failed, so clean up the filesystem
cleanUp(output, file)

// throw any exception that occurred along the way
op2.get
```

Assume that throwing exceptions is a legitimate design choice for this function, the calling process expects exceptions to be thrown and handles them gracefully.

Comment: You could just combine both code blocks into one, so that only one is reviewed.

Comment: oh duh, hi, this is me overthinking a plate of beans...

Comment: I have never coded in Scala but you can use a try-catch-finally block and also what's the point of catching an exception if you are throwing it back without changing it ? & use better variable names & also don't add obvious comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be written more cleanly with `flatMap`

> `flatMap[U](f: (T) ⇒ Try[U]): Try[U]`
>
> Returns the given function applied to the value from this `Success` or returns this if this is a `Failure`.

```
val isReportSent = Try {
 ...
}.flatMap(_ => Try { sendReport(...) })

cleanUp(output, file)

isReportSent.get
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using ARM (Automatic Resource Management) to clean up your resources. In Scala, there is a library available called [scala-arm](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/).

Then your code could be structured something like:

```
import resource._
import scala.util.Try

for {
  connection ← managed(DB.getConnection())
  output ← managed(...)
  file ← managed(...)
} {
  val result = for {
    report ← Try(generateReport(...)(output, connection))
    sendResult ← Try(sendReport(..., file))
  } yield sendResult
  // throws exception from generateReport or sendReport
  result.get 
}
```

The details of cleaning up your resources would either be handled by the default behavior in scala-arm, or if you need to define custom clean up behavior you can create your own implementation of the Resource trait. You could create an implicit object in the companion object of your resource. The following snippet shows what methods can be overridden; only the close() implementation being required:

```
class MyOutput {}

object MyOutput {
  implicit object OutputResource extends Resource[MyOutput] {
    override def open(r: MyOutput): Unit = super.open(r)
    override def closeAfterException(r: MyOutput, t: Throwable): Unit = super.closeAfterException(r, t)
    override def isFatalException(t: Throwable): Boolean = super.isFatalException(t)
    override def isRethrownException(t: Throwable): Boolean = super.isRethrownException(t)
    override def close(r: MyOutput): Unit = ???
  }
}
```